# How to set an id with a belongs_to and has_many association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5 to set up an API for my React frontend. I have a `Team` and `Player` model. After creating this model, I added an association by running `rails g migration AddTeamToPlayers team:references`. Each team should be set up to `has_many` players and players `belongs_to` a team.

When I try to create a new player, I see that the team association has added a `team_id`, but its set to `null`. How do I pass each player a team to be associated with?

**players_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @player = Player.new(player_params)
    @player.save

    render json: @player, status: :created
end
```

**player.rb**

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :team
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :players
end
```

When I try to `POST`:

```
{
    "name": "Randy Moss",
    "position": "WR",
    "team_id": 27
}
```

the player created still has `team_id: null`. How can I set a `team_id` when creating a new player?

Comment: do you have `team_id` in strong params?

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I had to set it in `strong params`. This solved the issue. Thank you @AneesMuhammed !

Comment: Glad that I could help